# SQL Query that makes the server hang?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

I wrote this query a while ago, and it seemed to work fine.

But lately when this query runs it often doesn't return any results. The Ajax call just never receives a response. It is the same if I run it in phpMyAdmin, often it works but sometimes it just hangs.

It is like that for a few hours, and then it starts to work fine again.

I'm not sure if there is problem with my query that makes the server choke, or if there is an issue on the server itself.

This is the query that runs. I'm no sql pro, so maybe someone notices a big issue with it that I should handle differently? If I run it, and I receive a response it it usually takes 1.5 / 2 sec to finish.

```
SELECT country.CountryID,
    accommodation.AccommodationID,
    accommodation.CityID,
    accommodation.lodgement,
    accommodation.SumID,
    accommodation.RegionID,
    accommodation.starrating,
    accommodation.reviewrating,
    images.image1 AS image,
    summary.name,
    summary.lowestprice,
    summary.lowestpricedate,
    summary.url
FROM country
    INNER JOIN accommodation ON accommodation.CountryID = country.CountryID
    INNER JOIN images ON images.AccommodationID = accommodation.AccommodationID
    INNER JOIN cities ON cities.CityID = accommodation.CityID
    INNER JOIN summary ON summary.SumID = accommodation.SumID
WHERE country.name = 'x'
ORDER BY accommodation.reviewrating DESC LIMIT 0,25
```

Comment: First: monitor the memory usage on your system, you might run out of memory for the temporary results, so the system starts swapping. Next use mysqls `explain` feature to check if you can optimize the query. Maybe your index definitions are not well suited.

Comment: If I had to take a wild guess, the table `images` doesn't have an index on `AccommodationId`, and this table has been growing over time.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have indexes on all columns used in the joins?

`country.CountryID`,  `accommodation.AccommodationID`, `cities.CityID` and `summary.SumID` all need to be primary keys.

`accommodation.CountryID`,  `images.AccommodationID`,  `accommodation.CityID`,  `accommodation.SumID` and `country.name` all need to have indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be on this line

```
ORDER BY accommodation.reviewrating DESC LIMIT 0,25
```

although using LIMIT MySQL must sort all your accommodation rows by reviewrating before selecting the first 25. Try creating a new index with:

```
CREATE INDEX ON accommodation (CountryID, reviewrating);
```

as you will probably notice the query is requiring a FULL SCAN on table accommodation.

Answer (score 0):

Without a lot of details on your schema and row counts in your tables, it's hard to know exactly why your query's performance has deteriorated. But I suspect it's because your tables are getting larger. Congratulations on a successful app, and welcome to the world of keeping an eye on your RDMS to make sure it continues to scale up properly.

The *deferred join* technique may prove very helpful.  That works like this.

First, figure out the `AccommodationID` values you need to report. In the query you are using, that can be done like this:

```
        SELECT AccomodationID
          FROM accomodation
          JOIN country USING(CountryID)
         WHERE country.name = 'x'
         ORDER BY reviewrating DESC
         LIMIT 0,25
```

If you make a compound index on `(CountryID, reviewrating)` this will be quite fast. (If you're working with MyISAM tables, make an compound index on `(CountryID, reviewrating, AccomodationID)`.)  It will pull out the IDs for the top 25 reviews.

Next, use your subquery -- your list of 25 items -- in your main query.

```
 SELECT country.CountryID,
    accommodation.AccommodationID,
    accommodation.CityID,
    accommodation.lodgement,
    accommodation.SumID,
    accommodation.RegionID,
    accommodation.starrating,
    accommodation.reviewrating,
    images.image1 AS image,
    summary.name,
    summary.lowestprice,
    summary.lowestpricedate,
    summary.url
FROM country
    INNER JOIN accommodation ON accommodation.CountryID = country.CountryID
    INNER JOIN images ON images.AccommodationID = accommodation.AccommodationID
    INNER JOIN cities ON cities.CityID = accommodation.CityID
    INNER JOIN summary ON summary.SumID = accommodation.SumID
    INNER JOIN (
            SELECT AccomodationID
              FROM accomodation
              JOIN country USING(CountryID)
             WHERE country.name = 'x'
             ORDER BY reviewrating DESC
             LIMIT 0,25
               ) ids ON accomodation.AccomodationId = ids.AccomodationId
ORDER BY accommodation.reviewrating DESC LIMIT 0,25
```

Why is this effective? It doesn't create a big result set and sort it only discard all except 25 rows. Instead it very precisely gathers the ids it needs using an already-ordered index, then creates a much smaller final result set.

This is called a *deferred join* because it defers the big join operation until after the correct subset of rows has been chosen.